# How do I prevent my laptop from switching to the integrated graphic card when it is not charging

Tags: graphics-card

How can i fix this? It's pretty annoying if I want to show anyone a game or something quick but then i can't  because I switches integrated card have my charger with me and then i'm very laggy :/

I have a MSI GT70 0ne dragon edition with a Nvida GTX 680M
I have tried to switch in the Nvida Control Panel all my settings to the "Nvidia Processor with high performance

any ideas?

Comment: Is your computer switching to the integrated graphics card, or is a game?  If it's a game, which one?  Does more than one game do it?

Comment: Yep all games :) I'ts my computer. Every time i unplug my "battery charger"  and i auto detect in a game, it changes all the settings to low.

Comment: So, the issue is, how to set your laptop to use power as if it is plugged in all the time, regardless of whether or not it actually is.

Answer (score 9):

I got a similar Laptop so solution will hopefully be the same

2 thing need to be changed

**1st**

> Control Panel, clicking System and Security, and then clicking Power Options.

Here change when not plugged in to performance

**2nd**

> Open NVIDIA control panel (Make sure your drivers are up to date), click Manage 3D settings, Power management mode, Prefer maximum performance

[image: NVIDIA]

This pretty much disabled my integrated card.

If this fails jump in device manager and disabled the integrated card(Results less then guaranteed - Perform at own risk)

Comment: +1 For lots of pictures. More questions should have pictures. Pictures are great.

Comment: Their is only 1 picture in this.... and yes pictures are good makes things a lot easier (something I wish I knew when I first started in IT Support)

Comment: Oh. Well whatever. Picture(s) are great.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me,

go to Device Manager

Expand the batteries tab.

Disable the Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery.

Seemed to stop the brightness from lowering and the usb devices from cutting out.

As well GPU didnt stutter in games like GTAV or CSGO.